# Do some North Korean math textbooks involve problems counting the "American imperialist" dead?

Tags: education, north-korea

['We Are the Mighty'](https://www.wearethemighty.com/mighty-trending/5-of-the-silliest-means-of-propaganda-used-by-north-korea/) writes about propaganda in North Korea:

> Their "history" and text books
>
> [...] The lies even slide into math problems for their kids. Such as:
>
> > During the Fatherland Liberation War, the brave uncles of Korean People's Army killed 265 American imperialist bastards in the first battle. In the second battle, they killed 70 more bastards than they had in the first battle. How many bastards did they kill in the second battle? How many American imperialist bastards did they kill altogether?

A bunch of other claims there like the [propaganda] story about unicorns in North Korean past are sourced to *Time* etc., which gives some degree of credibility to the page as a whole. However this particular claim about math education isn't sourced. So, is it true, do such "American imperialist" dead-counting problems appear in North Korean textbooks?

Comment: I checked https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propaganda_in_North_Korea but it doesn't something like this.

Comment: I think the origin of this claim is [Andrei Lankov and this 2011 webpage](https://www.koreatimes.co.kr/www/opinion/2023/11/638_93651.html). (There is a book titled _The Real North Korea: Life and Politics in the Failed Stalinist Utopia_ written by him was published by Oxford in 2015, which includes the context of that web page)